# Does editing a question from only the review page increases the count of the review queue?

Tags: support, review

I have been reviewing some questions and I have noticed that if I review a question from the review page then it adds in my review queue. But if I edit a question from any other a page then it does not add up in my review queue. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. If you are editing (or suggesting edit) direct from the post page then the review count doesn't add up in your review queue because by this way you are not reviewing any particular post but just improving the post!

Comment: With additional benefit that you are not limited with 20 edits.

Comment: But sometimes when I check the review queue it is empty but there are many First Posts by new users on the questions page. Why is this so?

Comment: @AnshumanJasrotia - The review queue is empty simply because the posts have already been reviewed by some other people.