# Improve edit does not increase edit count

Tags: discussion, review, edits

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170155/189165) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/189165) explains, why my review count does not increase, when editing a question directly from the review page / review queue.

But, why my *edit count* does not increase, when I hit `Improve Edit` button?

Many times I've run into situation, where someone just added or removed tags and left the entire post very messy, so I had to spent 5-10 minutes to re-edit it entirely. For me, it was a full feature edit of that post, but my edit count wasn't increased only, because I made that edit directly from review screen.

This is probably by design. But, why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just clicking "Improve Edit" shouldn't increment anything since you haven't actually edited anything yet.

The edit count only increments when your edit is live on the post, this means as soon as you make your changes and submit your edit.  And I just verified this behavior when reviewing [your own edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/32611).  My edit count did increment one as soon as I clicked submit to my improvement your edit.

Comment: I misunderstood this functionality. Of course, I was talking about actually submitting edited changes, not just hitting `Improve Edit`. Somehow, I was forced to think, that such edits does not count and does not update edit count. It turned out to be not true. Thank you for reviewing and explaining this to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through what I thought to be the same problem... but everything is working fine.

In my particular case, it took more than 15 min for some edits to be considered by the system.

Comment: Which is exactly the same as the answer of 6 years ago says.

Comment: Not the same, it references times @Luuklag. I thought the answer was wrong (from the sense that it worked back then but not now) until I saw it myself (and that took more than 15 min even though I wasn't placed in a queue).